# Analyzing the decay rate of Taylor series coefficients when high-order derivatives are intractable

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, generating-functions, taylor-series

This could be a soft question. I am trying to show that the $n$-th Taylor series coefficient of a function is $O(n^{-5/2})$. However, because the function is a function composition of another function with itself, it seems intractable to compute high-order derivatives. I was wondering if there are methods that can bound the asymptotic decay rate of Taylor series coefficients without obtaining the exact coefficients. For example, can complex analysis help here?

Thank you so much!

---

The function that I am trying to analyze is $f(x)=g(g(x))$, where $g(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\left( x\cdot (\pi-\arccos(x)) + \sqrt{1-x^2} \right)$. I conjecture that its $n$-th Taylor coefficient about $x=0$ is $O(n^{-5/2})$. I have shown that the $n$-th Taylor coefficient of $$g(x)= \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{x}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-1)n!2^n \pi} x^{2n}$$ is $O(n^{-5/2})$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complex analysis can help. The rate of Taylor coefficients is determined by:

a) the radius of convergence, which is equal to the radius of the largest disk $|z|<r$
where your function is analytic. This radius is responsible for the exponential asymptotics, and

b) the nature of singularities on the circle $|z|=r$.

Your function $f$ can have only square root singularities, since $g$ has only square root singularities. Since the singularities of $g$ are $\pm1$, to determine the radius of convergence, you have to show that equation $g(z)=\pm1$ has no solutions
in $|z|<1$. This will justify your asymptotics.

I have not done the calculation, perhaps you can do it yourself.

Ref: P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick, Analytic combinatorics, Chap. VI.

Edit: Conrad gave a simple argument in the comment below below which shows that $f$ has no other
singularities in the closed unit disk, except at $z=\pm1$, so your conjecture on the asymptotics is correct.

Comment: Thank you Professor Eremenko! Can complex analysis give a fine-grained rate, like n^{-5/2}?

Comment: Yes, of course. Even finer than that, like $\sim cn^{-5/2}$ where $c$ can be also computer, and higher order terms as well. The difficulty in justifying this is showing that there are no singularities of $f$ in the unit disk, except those of $g$. But I believe this fact can be even checked with a computer, if no simple argument is found.

Comment: Thank you so much Professor Eremenko! I am reading Chap VI of Analytic combinatorics and see if I can figure it out myself. I learned a really helpful tool from you.

Comment: @Cechco: The main part which is somewhat doubtful is solving the equation $g(x)=1$, not the Chap VI of Flajolet.

Comment: $g$ has positive coefficients so $|g(x)| \le g(|x|) <g(1)=1, |x| < 1$

Comment: @Conrad: Thanks! I just tried to verify this on Maple:-)

Comment: I thought you were initially interested in solutions in $|z|\le1$ rather than only in $|z|<1$.

Comment: Yes, but since the coefficients are positive, and $g(1)=1$, I conclude that $1$ is the ONLY solution of $g(z)=1$ in $|z|\leq 1$. Moreover, since $g'(1)\neq 0$, the nature of all singularities of $f$ in $|z|\leq 1$ is  clear.

Comment: Now that I have looked at Ch. VI you referred to (especially Theorem VI.5 there), it seems to me that we have to have the analyticity of $f$, not just in the unit disk, but also in a certain kind of domain containing points not in the unit disk.

Comment: Our function has isolated singularities on the boundary. In fact only one singularity. Subtracting the elementary function with the same singularruty we obtain that the difference is analytic in the larger disk, therefore the contribution from this difference to the Taylor series is negligibly small.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I am sorry for all these continuing questions, as I have absolutely no real experience in this area and am trying to learn. However, (i) I think here we have **two** points of singularity on the unit circle, $\pm1$. (ii) Finding elementary functions mimicking the singularities does not seem quite obvious to me. (iii) Here we also have branch cuts going from $\pm1$ outside the unit disk, and so, it does not seem possible to extend $g$ analytically to an entire larger disk. (iv) we also seem to have to ensure that $g$ does not map any "good" point to a cut.

Comment: Yes, two points, $-1,1$. The contributions from them are added. Branch cut is irrelevant here. Both singularities are of the form (some power)+analytic function. When we subtract those powers the remainder has radius of convergence $>1$, so it can be neglected and only powers contribute. These powers have explicit expansions at 0. The computation in your answer seems correct to me.

Comment: I think the subtraction would work if we only had $g$, but we actually have $f=g\circ g$. So, I think we do have to take care of point (iv) in my previous comment.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: by "subtraction" I mean "subtraction of the main term with non-integer exponent" and "neglecting all other terms with non-integer exponent". In other words, all we need for asymptotics of coefficients is the principal terms of expansion of $g\circ g$ near $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I still think that we can restrict our worries about $g\circ g$ to just the points $\pm1$ **only** after taking care of the previously listed point (iv): to ensure that $g$ does not map any "good" point to a cut.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: I agree with the first part of your sentence, and this is the same that I said (there are only two points $\pm$ to consider), but the second part of the sentence I do not understand: what do you refer to as (iv)? And the "cuts" are irrelevant here.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Point (iv) was first stated in my big four-point comment and restated in my last comment: that we seem to have to ensure that $g$ does not map any "good" point to a cut. What I mean here is the following. Let $\mathbf D$ be a domain as in Theorem VI.5 you referred to, with $\rho=1$ and $\zeta_{1,2}=\pm1$, so that $\mathbf D$ contains some points outside the unit disc.

Comment: Previous comment continued: It would be bad if $g$ mapped some point of $\mathbf D$ to a branch cut for $g$, because then $g\circ g$ would not be analytic in $\mathbf D$. I did not see this bad situation taken care of in your answer. So, I thought this could be something quite trivial, but so far I don't see such a trivial way to deal with this.

Comment: We know that $g$ maps $\overline{D}$ into $D\cup\{1\}$. So there is always a cut from $1$ outside $f(D)$..

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Alas, I don't understand your latest comment. In particular, what do you mean by "a cut" -- a cut for $g$ or for $f$? Also, I don't see how the 1st sentence in that comment implies the 2nd one (except that $g$ obviously has a cut, even two cuts). Most importantly, I don't see at all how that comment addresses the concern expressed in my most recent two-part comment: to ensure that $g$ does not map any "good" point to a cut.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: I was talking about the cut of g. Since $g$ maps the unit disk into itself $g=g\circ g$ also does. So there are no problems with slit. But I do not understand this long discussion: your argument in your answer seems correct to me, what else are you trying to find out? –

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : As I wrote in a previous comment: "It would be bad if $g$ mapped some point of $\mathbf D$ to a branch cut for $g$, because then $g\circ g$ would not be analytic in $\mathbf D$. I did not see this bad situation taken care of in your answer. So, I thought this could be something quite trivial, but so far I don't see such a trivial way to deal with this." This has been the main point I have been trying to clarify.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: I think I clarified this point in my previous comment: if $g$ is analytic in the unit disk and maps the unit disk into itself, then evidently $g\circ g$ is analytic in the unit disk and maps the unit disk into itself as well. Do you disagree with this statement?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: And I do not claim that my answer contains a compete solution: read the sentence: "I have not done the calculation...". I only explained how one can do it. And you did it. So what is the point of further discussion?

Answer (score 9):

Note that $g(1)=g'(1)=1$ and for real $x\in(-1,1)$
\begin{equation*}
    g''(x)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
\end{equation*}
The map $z\mapsto1-z^2$ maps the set
\begin{equation*}
    R:=\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,-1]\setminus[1,\infty)
\end{equation*}
onto $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$. So, the map
\begin{equation*}
    R\ni z\mapsto h(z):=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{1-z^2}}
\end{equation*}
is analytic, and hence $g$ can be continued analytically to $R$ by the Taylor formula
\begin{equation*}
    R\ni z\mapsto g(z):=g(1)+g'(1)(z-1)+\int_1^z(z-u)h(u)\,du \\
    =z+\int_1^z(z-u)h(u)\,du. \tag{0}
\end{equation*}

Take a real $r>1$ and let
\begin{equation*}
    D_r:=\{z\in R\colon|z|<r,|\arg(z-1)|>\pi/4\}. 
\end{equation*}
The main difficulty is to show that $g(D_r)\subseteq R$ for some $r>1$.

First here, take any real $t>0$. Then there is some real $u_t>0$ such that for all complex $z$ with $|z|\le1$ and $|\arg z|\ge t$ we have $|\frac1\pi+\frac z2|\le\frac1\pi+\frac12-u_t$, whence
\begin{equation*}
    |g(z)|\le\Big|\frac1\pi+\frac z2\Big|+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-1)n!2^n \pi}|z|^{2n}
    \le\frac1\pi+\frac12-u_t+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-1)n!2^n \pi}
    =g(1)-u_t=1-u_t. 
\end{equation*}
Since $g$ is analytic on $R$, it is uniformly continuous on any compact subset of $R$. So, there is some real $r_t>1$ such that $|g(z)|<1$ for all complex $z\ne1$ with $|z|\le r_t$ and $|\arg z|\ge t$.
Also, it follows that $|g(z)|<1$ for all complex $z$ with $|z|<1$.

Thus, to prove that $g(D_r)\subseteq R$ for some $r>1$, it suffices to show that
$\Im g(z)\ne0$ for all $z\ne1$ with $|z|\ge1$ and $|\arg(z-1)|>\pi/4$ that are close enough to $1$.

To see this, note that $h(u)\sim\frac1{\pi\sqrt2\,\sqrt{1-u}}$ as $u\to1$. Then (0) yields
\begin{equation*}
g(z)=z+c_1\cdot(z-1)^{3/2}, \tag{1} 
\end{equation*}
where $c_1=c_1(z)$ converges to a nonzero complex number as $z\to1$. So, the conclusion that
$\Im g(z)\ne0$ for all $z\ne1$ with $|z|\ge1$ and $|\arg(z-1)|>\pi/4$ that are close enough to $1$ follows, which does show that $g(D_r)\subseteq R$ for some $r>1$.

So, $f=g\circ g$ is analytic on $D_r$ for such an $r$.

Moreover, (1) implies
\begin{equation*}
    f(z)=g(g(z))=g(z+c_1\cdot(z-1)^{3/2})\\ 
    =z+c_1\cdot(z-1)^{3/2}+\hat c_1\cdot(z-1+c_1\cdot(z-1)^{3/2})^{3/2} \\
    =z+\tilde c_1\cdot(z-1)^{3/2}, \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where $\hat c_1=\hat c_1(z)\sim c_1(z)$ and $\tilde c_1=\tilde c_1(z)\sim2c_1(z)$ as $z\to1$.

Similarly, since $h(u)\sim\frac1{\pi\sqrt2\,\sqrt{1+u}}$ as $u\to-1$, the Taylor formula for $g(z)$ at $z=-1$ (together with the observation $g(-1)=g'(-1)=0$) yields $g(z)=c_{-1}\cdot(z+1)^{3/2}$, where $c_{-1}=c_{-1}(z)$ converges to a complex number as $z\to-1$. Therefore and because $g$ is analytic at $0$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(z)=g(g(z))=c_0+\hat c_0\cdot g(z)
    =c_0+\tilde c_0\cdot(z+1)^{3/2}, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where $c_0:=g(0)$, $\hat c_0=\hat c_0(z)=O(1)$, and $\tilde c_0=\tilde c_0(z)=O(1)$ as $z\to-1$.

Now we are finally in a position to use (with thanks to Alexandre Eremenko) [Theorem VI.5](https://archive.org/details/Flajolet_and_Sedgewick__Analytic_combinatorics) (with $\alpha=-3/2$, $\beta=0$, $\rho=1$, $r=2$, $\zeta_1=1$, $\zeta_2=-1$, $\mathbf D=D_r$, $\sigma_1(z)=z$, $\sigma_2(z)=c_0$), which yields the $n$th coefficient for $f$:
\begin{equation*}
    [z^n]f(z)=O(n^{\alpha-1})=O(n^{-5/2}), 
\end{equation*}
as you conjectured.

---

For an illustration, here is the set $\{g(z)\colon z\in R,|z|<2\}$:

[image]

Comment: while the idea is right, not sure your analysis is quite correct since $g(1-r)$~$1-r-cr^{3/2}, r>0, r \to 0$ which gives $f(1-r)$ a $3/2$ singularity too, so the coefficients are $O(n^{-5/2})$; it may be easier seen taking derivatives since $g'(1-r)$~$1-c_1r^{1/2}$ so $f'=(g'\circ g)g'$ is also $1-c_2r^{1/2}$ so $f'$ has coefficients $O(n^{-3/2})$ etc

Comment: @Conrad : Thank you for your comment. More recently, I too have realized that $-5/4$ cannot be right. I had, rather blindly, relied on Mathematica in computing the composition $f=g\circ g$ and its asymptotics at $z=1$. Apparently, there was a mistake either in my or Mathematica's coding. I have now redone this part of the proof (more) manually, which hopefully yields the correct result.

Comment: I think now all is good - since $g$ "contracts" the unit disc it didn't make sense to get a worse estimate for the coefficients of $f=g \circ g$ (while we cannot get a better one because of positivity of the coefficients and the fact that $f(x)=g(x)/2+\sum {b_nx^n}, b_n \ge 0$)

Comment: Thank you so much Professor Pinelis for your detailed proof! I have a quick question: Theorem VI.5 assumes that $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are a linear combination of elements from $\{(1-z)^{-\alpha} \lambda(z)^\beta| \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}\}$. To see this, notice that $z$ is in $\operatorname{span}\{(1-z)^{-\alpha} \lambda(z)^\beta| \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}\}$ (because $z=-(1-z)+1$) and a constant $c_0$ is also there. Am I right?

Comment: @Cechco : Yes, any polynomial in $z$ is such a linear combination, and it clearly does not affect the asymptotics of the coefficients as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I am sorry there is one thing I tried two days but couldn't understand. I was wondering why checking the function values of the boundary points of $R$ implies $g$ maps $R$ into $R$. It seems to me that $\partial g(R)\subseteq g(\partial R) = \{0,1,\infty\}\cup \{g(s\pm 0i)| |s|>1\}$. However, I couldn't prove that $g(\partial R) = \partial g(R)$ if it is true. If it happens to be true, I have a perhaps feasible argument: assume there is a point $z$ that gets mapped to, say, $[1,\infty)$ (similar for $(-\infty,-1]$. Note that $g(0)=1/\pi$.

Comment: 2/2: Consider a path that connects $0$ and $z$. Then the image of the path (it connects $1/\pi$ and $g(z)\ge 1$) will cross the curve $\{ g(s\pm 0i| s\ge 1 \}$ by an argument like Jordan curve theorem. But I couldn't prove $g(\partial R)=\partial g(R)$. My question may be stupid. I am sorry for it.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I got some numerical results from Mathematica tonight, which made me a little confused. There seems to be two rays starting from $-1$ and going to $\infty$ that get mapped to $(-\infty,-1]$. The real part of the two rays is $\le -1$. I used the following code: g[u_] := (Sqrt[1 - u^2] + u (Pi - ArcCos[u]))/Pi; ContourPlot[Im[g[a + b I]] == 0, {a, -100, 0}, {b, -1, 100}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]

Comment: @Cechco : You cannot get $\Re g\le-1$ on the entire two rays emanating from $-1$, because $g(-1)=0$.

Comment: @Cechco : As for the containment  $g(D)\subseteq R$ for an adequate domain $D$ -- which is the crucial part of the proof, I did that previously in some haste, having in mind principles of boundary correspondence such as ones in https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/colloquium-mathematicum/all/139/1/87556/a-topological-dichotomy-with-applications-to-complex-analysis or https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2960.pdf . That did not work quite well, though. I have now redone that part of the proof. Hopefully, this is correct now.